# Apache Commons SCXML - cannot find JexlContext

Tags: java, scxml, apache-commons-scxml

I'm new to SCXML and I cannot start even the simplest application. When I try to start it I get the following exception. But I have the library `commons-scxml-0.9.jar` with that class on classpath. Any ideas?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/jexl/JexlContext
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at org.apache.commons.scxml.env.AbstractStateMachine.<init>(AbstractStateMachine.java:103)
at main.StateMachineImpl.<init>(StateMachineImpl.java:8)
at main.Main.main(Main.java:6)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.jexl.JexlContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 15 more
```

Here is the code:

`Main class`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StateMachineImpl stateMachineImpl = new StateMachineImpl();
        stateMachineImpl.fireEvent(Event.START.getEvent());
        stateMachineImpl.fireEvent(Event.STOP.getEvent());
    }
}
```

`Event`

```
public enum Event {

    START("event.start"), STOP("event.stop");

    private String event;

    private Event(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

}
```

`StateMachineImpl`

```
public class StateMachineImpl extends AbstractStateMachine {

    public StateMachineImpl() {
        super(StateMachineImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResource("state-machine-cfg.xml"));
    }

    public void off() {
        System.out.println("StateMachine is OFF");
    }

    public void running() {
        System.out.println("StateMachine is RUNNING");
    }

}
```

`state-machine-cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml" version="1.0"
    initialstate="off">

    <state id="off">
        <transition event="event.start" target="running" />
    </state>

    <state id="running">
        <transition event="event.stop" target="off" />
    </state>

</scxml>
```

**EDIT - solution:**
I have to add additional dependencies (I thought they would be loaded by Maven automatically).

`pom.xml dependencies`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-scxml</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-scxml</artifactId>
    <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-jexl</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-jexl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I like the pom.xml solution the best, good work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`commons-jexl.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-jexl/commons-jexl/1.1/commons-jexl-1.1.jar) to the CLASSPATH as well. According to the project [`pom.xml`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-scxml/commons-scxml/0.9/commons-scxml-0.9.pom) in version 0.9 you will also need (excluding transitive depndencies):

- `commons-logging`
- `commons-digester`
- `commons-beanutils`
- `commons-el`

Comment: Thank you. I only had to add `commons-logging`, `commons-jexl` and `xalan` libraries.

Answer (score 1):

All SCXML dependency jars can be found here:

http://commons.apache.org/scxml/dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem almost 12 years after the question. The answser are not working for the current version of [common-scxml2](https://github.com/apache/commons-scxml). I found a soultion with adding the currently needed version of jexl3.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-jexl3</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
```